# how to remove this object from array inside of object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not sure how to form this question, but I will do my best.
I don't know how to remove object by _id from 'list:' part.
So, I have one array, and inside of that array I have list of objects,inside of these objects I have again array with objects, so I want to remove one object from that last array, how I can do that?
Cannot fix it for 2 days, I'm stucked!
Thanks!

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "599a1344bf50847b0972a465",
    "title": "British Virgin Islands BC",
    "list": [],
    "price": "1350"
  },
  {
    "_id": "599a1322bf50847b0972a38e",
    "title": "USA (Nevada) LLC",
    "list": [
      {
        "_id": "599a1322bf50847b0972a384",
        "title": "Nominee Member",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "300"
      },
      {
        "_id": "599a1322bf50847b0972a385",
        "title": "Nominee Manager & General Power of Attorney (Apostilled)",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "650"
      },
      {
        "_id": "599a1322bf50847b0972a386",
        "title": "Special Power of Attorney",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "290"
      }
    ],
    "price": "789"
  },
  {
    "_id": "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2ad",
    "title": "Cyprus LTD",
    "list": [
      {
        "_id": "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2a5",
        "title": "Nominee Shareholder",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "370"
      },
      {
        "_id": "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2a6",
        "title": "Nominee Director & General Power or Attorney (Apostilled)",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "720"
      },
      {
        "_id": "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2ab",
        "title": "Extra Rubber Stamp",
        "service": "other-service",
        "price": "40"
      }
    ],
    "price": "1290"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please post the json here

Comment: Can you put the JSON in text? It's easier to work with.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hW31Gwbz

Comment: we need more context as to where in this JSON is the item that you want to remove.  Showing your code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Vanilla JS:

```js
function findAndRemove(data, id) {

  data.forEach(function(obj) {                    // Loop through each object in outer array

    obj.list = obj.list.filter(function(o) {      // Filter out the object with unwanted id, in inner array
      return o._id != id;
    });
  });
}

var data = [{
    "_id": "599a1344bf50847b0972a465",
    "title": "British Virgin Islands BC",
    "list": [],
    "price": "1350"
  },
  {
    "_id": "599a1322bf50847b0972a38e",
    "title": "USA (Nevada) LLC",
    "list": [{
        "_id": "599a1322bf50847b0972a384",
        "title": "Nominee Member",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "300"
      },
      {
        "_id": "599a1322bf50847b0972a385",
        "title": "Nominee Manager & General Power of Attorney (Apostilled)",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "650"
      },
      {
        "_id": "599a1322bf50847b0972a386",
        "title": "Special Power of Attorney",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "290"
      }
    ],
    "price": "789"
  },
  {
    "_id": "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2ad",
    "title": "Cyprus LTD",
    "list": [{
        "_id": "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2a5",
        "title": "Nominee Shareholder",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "370"
      },
      {
        "_id": "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2a6",
        "title": "Nominee Director & General Power or Attorney (Apostilled)",
        "service": "nominee-service",
        "price": "720"
      },
      {
        "_id": "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2ab",
        "title": "Extra Rubber Stamp",
        "service": "other-service",
        "price": "40"
      }
    ],
    "price": "1290"
  }
];

// Empty almost all of list, except middle one
findAndRemove(data, "599a1322bf50847b0972a384");
findAndRemove(data, "599a1322bf50847b0972a386");
findAndRemove(data, "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2a5");
findAndRemove(data, "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2a6");
findAndRemove(data, "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2ab");

console.log(data);
```

> Cleared everything except middle list, just for better visualization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to accomplish this. Detailed explanation in comments:

PS: This snippet uses ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
function removeById(arr, id) {
  // Array.map iterates over each item in the array,
  // and executes the given function on the item.
  // It returns an array of all the items returned by the function.
  return arr.map(obj => {

    // Return the same object, if the list is empty / null / undefined
    if (!obj.list || !obj.list.length) return obj;

    // Get a new list, skipping the item with the spedified id
    const newList = obj.list.filter(val => val._id !== id);

    // map function returns the new object with the filtered list
    return { ...obj, list: newList };
  });
}

const oldArray = <YOUR_ORIGINAL_ARRAY>;
const newArray = removeById(arr, "599a12fdbf50847b0972a2a5");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abhijit Kar your one is working perfectly, thanks mate!
How I can later splice this list?
When I was working with objects from first array, I did it like this :

```
var inventory = jsonArrayList;    
for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
            if (inventory[i]._id == deleteProductById) {
              vm.items.splice(i, 1);
              break;
            }
          }
```

It would be very helpful, thanks alot!